# Pass Parameter to Custom NLog Appender

Tags: c#, app-config, nlog

I have a custom NLog appender.

```
    [Target("MyAppender")] 
    public sealed class MyAppender : TargetWithLayout
    {
        public int MyId{ get; set; }

        protected override void Write(LogEventInfo loggingEvent)
        {
        ...
        }
     }
```

I want to pass in MyId from the configuration file

I have this in my configuration file

```
...
<targets>
    <target xsi:type="MyAppender" name="MyAppender" />
<targets>
 <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="MyAppender" />
 <rules>
...
```

What do I need to add to my config file to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
<target xsi:type="MyAppender" name="MyAppender" myId="42" />
```

Comment: I assume, the property is named `PublicationId` in your class as well - and not `MyId` as you indicated in your question?

Comment: Correctly assumed.